# Django: Including a form inside a listview

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to insert a newsletter signup form into my base.html template which is a listview that displays upcoming events and featured shops and everytime I submit the form it returns a 'HTTP error 405'

Any help with this would be appreciated

> Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, TemplateView
from events.models import Event
from newsletter.forms import NewsletterSignUpForm
from shops.models import Shop


class HomeListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'core/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'events': Event.get_upcoming_events()[:1], # returns only the first event in the list
            'shops': Shop.objects.all(),
        })
        context['newsletter_form'] = NewsletterSignUpForm()
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return None
```

> forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Newsletter

class NewsletterSignUpForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Newsletter
        fields = ['email']
```

> Models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Newsletter(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    date_subscribed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.email}'
```

> base.html

```html
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ newsletter_form|crispy }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign Up!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

first add action url in form to handle post data

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'submit_url' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ newsletter_form|crispy }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Sign Up!</button>
</form>
```

**urls.py**

add url

```
path('your_url',views.formSubmit,name='submit_url')
```

**views.py**

```
def formSubmit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewsletterSignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('your_list_view_url')
```

or you can use `FormMixin` along with classbased views
[formmixin with classbased views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-formmixin-with-detailview)